# Add more than two windows in SplitView macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, osx-el-capitan

Is there any workaround that enables adding more than two windows in the SplitView introduced in El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can use BetterTouchTool for creating own snap area:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpxNQqIZcTk

It is not SplitView but can help you.